# DDD Factory and domain object properties

Tags: domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

Is DDD Factory allowed to set properties directly for domain object?
Such as:

```
public class DomainObjectFactory
{
    public DomainObject CreateForUser(int userId)
    {
        var domainObject = new DomainObject();
        domainObject.UserId = userId;
    }

}
```

Comment: It would mean that you do not follow the always-valid paradigm. I tend to favor this approach, but not everyone does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way to **create** domain entities would be to do so with constructor(s). So you accept required parameters through one or more constructors.

If you use domain factories, nothing changes that. A domain factory is used when entity creation is more complex, for example, from multiple objects or where some logic is involved during the creation, but you would still use the entity's constructor to create them.